# ImportError: No module named 'f2'

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, import, python-import, importerror

Suppose i have dir structure like below:

CommonDir1:
    ----dir2:
    ---------        f1.py
    ---------  f2.py
  ----dir3:
      ---------  f3.py

Now, here, f2 is imported in f1. everything works fine.
but when am importing f1 in f3. its throws error like:
ImportError: No module named 'f2'

Comment: how are you trying to import the module ?

Comment: in f1:  from f2 import x .  and in f3: from ..dir2 import f1 as tc1

Comment: you also need a file `__init__.py`  in each folder dir2 and dir3

Comment: This is really depends on how you manage your folder structure. Is `CommonDir1` just a common folder or you think it is a package? In other word, `dir2` & `dir3` are one package or just two packages put together under `CommonDir1`? And when you say call from `f3`, `f3.py` is your `top script` or you have another top script out of `CommonDir1` which will call `f3.py` as a module. Python is complex when handle packages for relative import etc things, you need clear specify your design, then we can show you a typical way to do it.

Comment: CommonDir1 is a package. dir 2 and dir 3 are two packages put together in CommonDir1. f3 is the top script actually, ill directly run f3.